# Sorting data (in a state) when state gets updated (React) - renders with delay

Tags: reactjs

I'm completely new to React and haven't been able to figure this out.

I'm trying to **sort a data array** saved in a state (`notes`). I need this to be reusable, so the sorting happens:

1. after clicking on a select that determines how the data should be sorted
2. after modifying the data itself (e.g. changing the title or updating the content).

I tried some alternatives and settled on saving `sort`, i.e. how the data should be sorted, in another state, and then using useEffect like this:

```
     const [notes, setNotes] = React.useState(notesInitial)
     const [sort, setSort] = React.useState('updated')

     function doSort(currentSort) {
        console.log("doing sort")
        switch (currentSort) {
            case "updated":
                setNotes(oldNotes => {
                    return oldNotes.sort((a,b) => {
                        return a.updated - b.updated
                    })
                });
                break;
            case "created":
                setNotes(oldNotes => {
                    return oldNotes.sort((a,b) => {
                        if (a.date > b.date) {
                          return 1
                      } else if (a.date < b.date) {
                          return -1
                      } else if (a.date == b.date) {
                          return 0
                      }
                    })
                });
                break;
            case "name":
                setNotes(oldNotes => {
                    return oldNotes.sort((a,b) => {
                        let titleA = a.title.toUpperCase();
                        let titleB = b.title.toUpperCase();
                        if (titleA > titleB) {
                          return 1
                      } else if (titleA < titleB) {
                          return -1
                      } else if (titleA == titleB) {
                          return 0
                      }
                    })});
            break;
        }
    }

    
    // sorting
    function changeSort(event) {
        setSort(event.target.value);
    }


    useEffect(()=>{
        doSort(sort);
        console.log(sort, notes)
    }, [sort, notes])
```

I was concerned about causing an infinite loop but from what I can tell, the useEffect() isn't causing one (?). However, the correctly sorted data in `notes` always renders with a delay. What am I doing wrong here and what's the alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to clone the array before you sort

```
 return [...oldNotes].sort((a,b) => {
        return a.updated - b.updated
 })
```

Otherwise react does not detect the change.

Also you run into the problem, that the useEffect will be called when notes are changed. This is true when you sort. So it will be called again and again.

Comment: Thank you! ...and yes, the infinite loop did show up after I rewrote it like this, I had to remove the dependency